# Override method in spring integration inbound channel adapter

Tags: java, class, gradle, overriding, spring-integration-sftp

I have a Spring Integration listener, where the `ApplicationContext` is something as follow:

```
final AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(

        // Spring Integration common xml
                "classpath:contexts/bp-common.xml",

                // File Upload Listener
                "classpath:contexts/bp-integration-fileupload-context.xml");
```

In Spring integration listener, I wish to ask the listener to rescan the folder everytime. So I do as follow:

```
Map< String, FileReadingMessageSource > fileReadingSourceMap = new HashMap< String, FileReadingMessageSource >( );

        fileReadingSourceMap = context.getBeansOfType( FileReadingMessageSource.class );

        List< FileReadingMessageSource > fileReadingSourceList = new ArrayList< FileReadingMessageSource >(
                fileReadingSourceMap.values( ) );

        for ( FileReadingMessageSource frms : fileReadingSourceList ) {
            frms.setScanEachPoll( true );
        }
```

I set the value of `scanEachPoll` to true, so that everytime it will rescan the directory again. Its work, I saw it scan the directory everytime. By default its false.

Edit a variable in `FileReadingMessageSource` class is not a problem. But I am facing some problem for edit a method inside this class.

There will be a method as follow in this class:

```
private void scanInputDirectory() {
        List<File> filteredFiles = scanner.listFiles(directory);
        Set<File> freshFiles = new LinkedHashSet<File>(filteredFiles);
        if (!freshFiles.isEmpty()) {
            toBeReceived.addAll(freshFiles);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Added to queue: " + freshFiles);
            }
        }
    }
```

Because of my modification, this listener will scan the directory everytime. Thus, `toBeReceived.addAll(freshFiles);` will keep adding some same file. I wish to do something to override this method, so that I can clean the `toBeReceived` Queue first before `addAll()`.

I believe `FileReadingMessageSource` class is come from `bp-integration-fileupload-context.xml` .

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="hostFilesOut" channel="hostFileOutChannel"
        directory="${hostfile.dir.out}" prevent-duplicates="false"
        filename-regex="${hostfile.out.filename-regex}" >
        <int:poller id="poller" cron="${poller.cron:0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56 * * * * * }"
            max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Anything I can "inject" into this xml portion to override the original `FileReadingMessageSource` class?

Or Kindly advise the better way to do it.

Maybe my question is confusing, let me add some example here:

actually its something like this:

Original version:

scanEachPoll is false by default.

So, scanInputDirectory() method wont be call everytime. It will only call when the Queue is empty.

But now, I change the scanEachPoll to true. ( This one can change easily )

When scanEachPoll is true, then scanInputDirectory() method will be call everytime, so it will something like:

1st time scan, add to queue (1,2,3,4,5)
poll(), become (2,3,4,5)
2nd time scan, add to queue will be (2,3,4,5) + (2,3,4,5) => become (2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5) 
poll(), become (2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
3rd time scan, add to queue will become original queue + (3,4,5) ==> become (2,3,3,4,4,5,5,3,4,5)
and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I manage to handle this problem by creating my own Scanner.

which is

```
<bean id="myDirectoryScanner" class="bp.main.myDirectoryScanner" ></bean>
```

My scanner only return the first item:

```
protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

        File[] rootFiles = directory.listFiles();
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(rootFiles.length);
        if ( rootFiles != null ) {
            files.add(rootFiles[0]);
        }
        return files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
    }
```